# Apache Felix OSGi logging with Logback

Tags: java, logging, osgi, apache-felix, blueprint-osgi

My current application uses [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) for logging. I have used Apache Felix to deploy an OSGi framework that allows bundles to be dynamically registered at runtime. The Felix setup is as follows:

```
    ...

    //System.out.println("Building OSGi Framework");
    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();

    // specify the class loader
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_PARENT, Constants.FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_PARENT_FRAMEWORK);

    // specify the osgi cache directory
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE, appConfig.getOsgiCacheDir());

    // make sure the cache is cleaned
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);

    // expose api
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA, "list.of.packages.to.export");

    // more properties available at: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html
    config.put("ds.showtrace", "false");
    config.put("ds.showerrors", "true");
    config.put("felix.fileinstall.dir", appConfig.getActiveOsgiExtDir());
    config.put("felix.fileinstall.tmpdir", appConfig.getTempOsgiExtDir());
    config.put("felix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient","true");
    config.put("felix.fileinstall.poll","5000");
    config.put("felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start", "true");

    LOG.debug("OSGi config: " + config.toString());

    framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);

    try {
        framework.init();
        FrameworkEvent event;

        do {
            framework.start();
    ...
```

The only problem is that there seems to be no logging with Felix. When a bundle fails to load for some reason I can't see why! I know that I can use the following in the bundle to obtain the parent logger:

```
ServiceReference ref = bundleContext.getServiceReference(LogService.class.getName());
if (ref != null) {
    LogService log = (LogService) bundleContext.getService(ref);
    ...
   }
```

However, I don't understand how I can get felix to use logback as the logger in the first place.

Comment: You don't need logging to work out why a bundle doesn't start. Just start it explicitly from the shell and observe the error message there.

Comment: Your absolutely correct. However, I do generically need to be able to perform logging and for bundles to be able to pass their logging to the main application framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you use [Apache Felix Log](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html) to have a LogService in you OSGi container. Apache Felix Log implements the chapter "*101 Log Service Specification*" of OSGi Enterprise Specification.

The basic of LogService implementation stores the logged entries for a while but does not write them to anywhere. You can query the recorded entries via *LogReaderService* or *LogListener*.

On the other hand, you might use Logback in the way that you added slf4j-api and slf4j-logback to your OSGi container. By doing that, everything that is logged via slf4j-api classes will be logged by logback.

If my guesses were right, the [osgi-loglistener-slf4j](https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-loglistener-slf4j) bundle could help you. This bundle does nothing else but registers a *LogListener* for every *LogReaderService* in the environment and forwards every log entries it catches to *slf4j-api*. The bundle is available on [maven-central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.everit.osgi%7Corg.everit.osgi.loglistener.slf4j%7C1.0.0%7Cbundle)

If you do not want to use slf4j API, you can write a similar bundle that does the log forwarding from *LogReaderService* to *Logback*. If you check the source of the bundle I linked, you will see that it is implemented with only a few lines of code.

Comment: I actually think you are 100% correct. However, I cant currently get the osgi-loglistener-slf4j to register without errors. Will update when this has been fixed.

Comment: `Unable to resolve org.everit.osgi.loglistener.slf4j [3](R 3.0): missing requirement [org.everit.osgi.loglistener.slf4j [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.everit.osgi.loglistener.slf4j [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]`

Comment: That is a bit strange. I guessed you used the LogService class from org.osgi.service.log package. Is it another LogService class? Without import package section in the sample code, I could not be sure. If it is from this package, what version of the package is included in your container?

Comment: Make sure than when using org.everit.osgi.loglistener.slf4j you ALSO install the Apache Felix Log bundle <http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html>, which offers the org.osgi.service.log package.